# Form Won't Submit With Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form

I am trying to add the following code to Contact Form 7 on Wordpress:

```
<div class="form">
<div class="f-name">
[text* your-name watermark "Name *"]
</div>

<div class="f-email">
[email* your-email watermark "Email *"]
</div>

<div class="f-subject">
[text your-subject watermark "Phone"]
</div>

<div class="f-message">
[textarea* your-message watermark "Message *"]
</div>

<div class="f-captcha">

<div class="f-captcha-insert">
[captchac captcha-886 size:l] 
</div>

<div class="f-captcha-CONFIRM">
[text* captchar captcha-886 size:m watermark "Please enter the characters above."]
</div>

</div>

<div class="bt-contact">
 <a class="btn-color btn-color-1d" href="javascript:;">[submit "SEND EMAIL"]</a>
</div>

</div>
```

When i click save, it get a 403 error notifying me that i do not have permission... however if i add just the normal default Contact Form 7, it ads fine.

I started removing the code from the above form until i found out what was causing the problem. The line below is causing the problem, but i am not sure why:

href="javascript:;"

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a link to submit a form?

Comment: I think what you want to do is something like: onclick="someFunction();". And why use a link? Use a button.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Form 7 submits should not be wrapped in a button. View the source of your rendered page, and you'll see why.

Change this line:

```
<a class="btn-color btn-color-1d" href="javascript:;">[submit "SEND EMAIL"]</a>
```

To this:

```
[submit class:btn-color class:btn-color-1d "SEND EMAIL"]
```

Comment: when i take out the link, i can no longer edit (click into) the input fields when a validation error is thrown